# Trouble floating elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two divs contained within a larger div and I'd like them to be laid next to each other. My approach was to float the first div left and set Overflow: hidden on the containing div.
For some reason it's not working and the 2nd div ends up ontop of the first.

Herse is the demo, http://jsfiddle.net/9xmDP/. I have some color coding which I was using to try and debug the overlapping. The code is also below. The signup form should be next to the login form instead of on-top of it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">    
<div id="signupDiv">
    <div id="signupLabel">
        SignUp
    </div>
    <form id="signupForm">
        User <input type="text" name="user"><BR/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="loginDiv">
    <div id="loginLabel">
          Login
    </div>            
    <form id="loginForm">
        User <input type="text" name="user"><BR/>
    </form>
</div>
```

​

**CSS**

```
    #container{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#signupLabel{
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 300px;
}

#signupDiv{
    float:left;
}

#loginLabel{
    border: solid red 1px;
    width: 300px;
    }

#loginDiv{
    width: 300px;
    border: solid pink 1px;
}
```

Comment: `#loginDiv{ overflow:hidden; ...etc}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css. fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9xmDP/5/)

```
#container{
width:604px;
}

#signupLabel{
border: solid black 1px;
width: 300px;
}

#signupDiv{
float:left;
width:300px;
}

#loginLabel{
border: solid red 1px;
width: 300px;
}

#loginDiv{
width: 300px;
float:left;
border: solid pink 1px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You need to `float:left` `#loginDiv` as well. See your updated fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xmDP/2/

Answer (score 1):

When you float an element, it is removed from the normal content flow, and any content in its parent element *and other children of the parent* tries to wrap around it.

So the `signupDiv` is indeed floated to the left, which puts it on top of the non-floating `loginDiv`.  The content in the `loginDiv` does try to wrap around the `signupDiv`, but since you've specified both elements to be 300px wide, there's no room for it, and so it must go *below* the floating div instead.

The simplest solution is to float *both* divs, like this:

```
#signupDiv, #loginDiv {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the divs next to each other, by making them both float.
If you make the container 605px, then the divs will fit in there (including the border)

```
#container{
    width: 605px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this

```
#loginDiv{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    border: solid pink 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Diplay:inline will also do the trick here..
http://jsfiddle.net/9xmDP/4/

```
#loginDiv{
width: 300px;
border: solid pink 1px;
display:inline-block;
}
```